# Question with using Isc -> Any errors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, norton, ideal

For the picture below, the answer for Voc is 7.5V, but when I add an Isc at terminals AB, and use KCL, I get Voc = 3.75V.

Here are my steps/equations:

(1) 15 = 4I1 - 2Isc

(2) 0 = 3Isc - 2I1

I get Isc = 15/4A, which is the same is Voc (15/4) or 1K*Isc.

[image]

Comment: For this particular circuit, that relationship is true, but it’s not generally the case

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Because it's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

\$V_{oc} = I_{sc} *R \$

Nope.

\$V_{oc}\$ mean **open-circuit voltage** across A and B. i.e, when those terminals are open. Now you shorted A and B to find \$I_{sc}\$.

Means, \$V_{oc}\$ = 0V now across A and B.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my loop equations though?

Comment: Its correct though.

Comment: But I still don't get 7.5V :(. Is my answer right then?

Comment: You won't get cz its not 7.5 when you short. Its 0 volts after shorting.

Comment: Ohhh, I miscalculated Rth wrong LOL. Thanks so much, once again!